PyQt6 Application Not Launching via Double-Click on .app File but Works with Executable Script in Terminal on macOS
I'm working on an application (that's only supposed to run on my machine) that uses PyQt6 to show a hello world text. I do not want to use py2app, pyinstaller or co. I manually created the app bundle and when running the bundle executable it fully works. Only when I double click the .app file (or open it via the terminal) it doesn't work. The osascript testing thing DOES work.
#!/bin/zsh

osascript -e 'display notification "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"'
cd /Volumes/Media/ExtPycharmProjects/baky-compiler
source /Volumes/Media/ExtPycharmProjects/baky-compiler/.venv/bin/activate
/Volumes/Media/ExtPycharmProjects/baky-compiler/.venv/bin/python3 ./example-app/executor.py

My Info.plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Example Application</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Example Application</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Example Application</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>

Bundle structure:
Example Application.app/
    Contents/
        MacOS/
            Example Application
        Resources/
        Info.plist

I want the application to start correctly and show the window.
